# Adding data dynamically to an Array

Tags: jquery

I have 3 dynamic divs which contains some json data. I need to add these divs into an array.
Please explain me as I am new to array manipulation.

Thanks in advance

I am using the below given code

$('body').append(''+ JSON.stringify(data) +'');

By using the above code I'm handling json into a div. Dynamically more divs has to be created

Comment: How do the `divs` contain JSON? Please provide an example of your HTML and an example of the result (the array) you want to get. As it is, the question is a bit vague. Also, you might find most helpful to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Hi Felix, I am using the below given code 
$('body').append('<div class="div1" style="display:none">'+ JSON.stringify(data) +'</div>'); By using the above code I'm handling json into a div. Dynamically more divs has to be created

Comment: Please *edit your question* and add the code there. So, eventually you want to get an array containing the data of each of the divs? You can just add the data to an array while you are creating the `divs`. `data` is already a native JavaScript data type, so there is no need to read the content of the `div`s and convert it. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object to learn how to work with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

to add an item to an array use the `.push()` method. See also http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp